# Is Google Cloud Storage an automagical global CDN?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I’m attempting to setup a Google Cloud Storage bucket to store and serve all the static objects for my site. I’m also attempting to push all the objects in that bucket out to all the global edge locations offered by Google Cloud CDN.

I’ve created a bucket on Google Cloud Storage: `cdn.mysite.com`. I chose “US” multi-region for the bucket `location` setting.

My assumption is that any object stored in this bucket will be replicated to all the `us-*` regions for high-durability purposes, but **not** pushed out to all the Google Cloud CDN global edge locations for CDN purposes.

Or are all my objects in my “US” multi-region bucket already automagically pushed out to all of Google Cloud CDN edge locations?

I’m gobsmacked that I can’t figure out whether or not my bucket is *already* a CDN or not. Even after two days of searching (Google, ironically).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 33):

The best discussion I've seen of Cloud Storage edge caching vs. Cloud CDN was during the Google Cloud Next '18 session ***Best Practices for Storage Classes, Reliability, Performance and Scalability***.  The entire video is useful, but here's [link](https://youtu.be/kNUlvj3vDWk?t=634) to the content distribution topic.

One key note from the summary is that edge caching gives you many of the benefits of a CDN, but you still pay for data egress. The Cloud CDN gives you caching, which can lower the cost of egress. They also outlined a couple other options.

[image]

Answer (score 25):

Cloud CDN and Cloud Storage are distinct, so objects in your multi-region bucket are not necessarily pushed to Cloud CDN edges. You can find information about Cloud Storage regions [here](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/#locations); as you probably already know, Cloud CDN's edge locations are mapped out [here](https://peering.google.com/#/infrastructure). **However, it's very straightforward to integrate Cloud Storage with Cloud CDN**: just follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/using-http-lb-with-cloud-storage#using_cloud_cdn_with_cloud_storage_buckets)!

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, Will! There's some misleading info out there about the nature of GCS that threw me off. Very helpful, thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome. :) Thanks for being a customer!

Comment: @Will, The link at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/serving-static-files says that "Cloud Storage essentially works as a content delivery network. This does not require any special configuration because by default any publicly readable object is cached in the global Cloud Storage network." Can you please help me understand if using CDN along with GCS is required for public web assets (static documents, CSS, etc.)?

Comment: @AnkurKanoria That must be where the blog post I found (but can't find again) got their info from. It ended up morphing into something like "Google Cloud Storage is already a CDN without any special setup". Telephone game.

Comment: @AnkurKanoria It's not required! But it does offer additional features and might reduce your latency.

Comment: That's $18/month just to add a load balancing rule to enable CDN with Cloud Storage? Ridiculous :/

Comment: @WillHayworth At this point I have to revoke my "answered" flag, To be honest, this still isn't clear. Have those of us paying for Google Cloud CDN been wasting money given that Google Cloud Storage is already a CDN? Can Google please provide an exact answer.

Comment: @AJB That question does not make sense. It's not like "being a CDN" is a 100% standardized definition. It's up to each person to decide what products and services they need. GCP GCS reaches certain locations, GCP CDN reaches certain other locations. They also differ in certain features, and also overlap in some features (such as signed URLs). The question is answered.

Comment: @thnee I couldn't disagree more. If you read the comment by Ankur Kanoria above the link does **specifically** state: "Cloud Storage essentially works as a CDN". And if that's true, then why are the rest of us paying for GCP CDN? It seems to me that Google's GCS infra was already designed to push everything out to their existing CDN, and now they're just selling that piece-meal to the public. What we're saying is that we think GCP CDN is phantom-ware, with a higher price tag.

Comment: @thnee Also, if you look at the age of this question, and the response that it's garnered from the dev community that should speak volumes. We wouldn't even be having this discussion if Google (a trillion-dollar global tech behemouth) could explain their product, and their pricing model succinctly. They have failed to do so. And this is one tiny example of the myriad ways that GCP will ultimately fail. It's important to notice that there is no SO question like this with regard to AWS Cloudfront, or Cloudflare, or Fastly, or any other CDN/Edge Provider. This is yet another Google fail.

Answer (score 8):

**Oct 2020 - Yes** - if you take [Google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/serving-static-files)'s word for it:

> Cloud Storage essentially works as a content delivery network. This
> does not require any special configuration because by default any
> publicly readable object is cached in the global Cloud Storage
> network.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/serving-static-files

Answer (score 7):

## Partly:

`Cloud Storage behaves like a Content Delivery Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable objects are cached in the Cloud Storage network by default.`

## But:

```
Feature                             Cloud Storage   Cloud CDN
Max cacheable file size             10 MiB          5 TiB
Default cache expiration            1 hour          1 hour (configurable)
Support custom domains over HTTPS   No              Yes
Cache invalidation                  No              Yes
```

In particular, if you serve videos to your users, they are likely to be larger than 10 MiB and will not be cached then.

Also note that it only uses caching for public objects.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching